# How can i convert a string into xml in JAVA which contains one attribute having value with angular brackets

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I got a situation when i need to convert my string into xml which contains
`"CGNAME="<Input>GROUP1</Input>"`

```
"<SOLRQUERY><I M="1" V="(1:2)OR(62:12)" CGNAME="<Input>GROUP1</Input>" BSLFLG="0" /></SOLRQUERY>"
```

in parameter I am passing above string

```
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(value);
Document CGXml = XPathReader.StringToXMLDocument(escaped);
```

And i am getting following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute
```

XPathReader is my inBuilt class and StringToXMLDocument function code i am putting.

```
public static Document StringToXMLDocument(String criteriaXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource isCriteriaXML = new InputSource();
    isCriteriaXML.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(criteriaXML));
    Document doc = db.parse(isCriteriaXML);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask question. Also additional info like: what have you tried to solve this problem, how did it not work (like what errors you see) would be very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Now lets not forget about adding information about what classes are you using because `StringEscapeUtils` or `XPathReader` doesn't belong to standard Java classes. I assume that `StringEscapeUtils` belongs to AppacheCommons, but cant say anything about second class.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the problem but maybe `excapeJava` use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml`. Can you say something more why you even want to escape your string?

Comment: Already tried same error.

Comment: Post info about `value`. How you initialize it?

Comment: value is coming from middle tier, so i did url encode for my value now its working perfectly.
Thanx for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape your characters. This means add \ before your "

For example:

```
CGNAME\"=\"GROUP1\"
```

So your String query would be:

```
"<SOLRQUERY>
    <I M=\"1\" V=\"(1:2)OR(62:12)\" CGNAME=\"<Input>GROUP1</Input>\" BSLFLG=\"0\" />
</SOLRQUERY>"
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But while converting it to xml i am getting error angular bracket not allowed.
Exact error is: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute.
I am using this function to convert to XML.
public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) 
            throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
    }

Comment: Check my update.. I think you forgot to add \ to all your " characters

Comment: with same hard coated string it is giving following error:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "CGNAME" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: Hmm ok. Well I'm no longer sure of whats the problem. The inital question was about making the query to string, now you have another problem that I cant solve.